# Como realizar uma aplicação com Banco de Dados em Android?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, android-studio, mobile

Estou iniciando minhas atividades no mundo mobile, e gostaria de construir uma aplicação que utilize Banco de Dados para plataforma Android, uma aplicação de exemplo para que eu possa seguir em frente, procurei na internet mas não ficou muito claro para mim como implementar para essa plataforma. Alguém poderia me ajudar com alguma indicação de como executar isso? Se possível também, alguém conhece algum link em que possa esclarecer como o Android trata manipulação de Banco de Dados em sua plataforma?

Comment: Veja esta minha [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645245/2556111) no SOen.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo de criação de um banco de dados no Android utilizando SQLite:

```
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    }
}
```

Referência: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Em `SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES` você informa os comandos SQL DML para a criação de tabelas, campos, alteração e remoção de campos.

O método `onCreate` irá ser chamado quando existe uma interação com o banco de dados SQLite e o banco de dados não foi criado ainda no dispositivo.

O método `onUpgrade` irá ser chamado quando existe uma interação com o banco de dados SQLite, o banco de dados já foi criado no dispositivo, porém o aplicativo no dispositivo foi atualizado e o banco de dados se encontra em outra versão.

Você pode colocar vários `db.execSQL` um em baixo do outro para a criação de determinada tabela, alteração de determinado campo, como você preferir.

Também existe a possibilidade do Android se comunicar externamente através de WebServices com um servidor que apresenta um banco de dados, como, por exemplo, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB (NoSQL, banco de dados orientado a documento) utilizando Java, PHP ou outra linguagem de programação para realizar a comunicação, normalmente é utilizado a arquitetura REST e retorna JSON para a aplicação.

Outros links úteis:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html
http://json.org/
http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/rest-introduction

Comment: Importante frisar que no caso de banco remoto os webservices são um intermediário necessário, mais recomendado que tentar estabelecer uma conexão direta do android com o banco remoto.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia. Se quiser criar uma base de dados numa Aplicação de Android. Isso vai depender de vários factores. primeiro, a aplicação corre em aquitectura servidor-cliente. ou não há comunicação com servidor, cloud whatever, e fica armazenado na base de dados do telemóvel. Pondo por palavras simples, tem de saber em primeiro lugar, se a base de dados é local ou remota. depois, creio que a melhor forma, pelo menos aquela que seguiria, seria criar uma base de dados de MySQL, ou uma arquitectura do estilo MongoDB (NoSQL, portanto), e criar variáveis na parte de Java, que liguem com a base de dados e que permitam fazer o respectivo input de dados. de certeza, que irá encontrar inúmero repositórios de github com inúmeros templates de bases de dados para Android, etc. se quiser, pode, contudo, optar por procurar em sites como o envato, codecanyon, e outras loJas online, por soluções similares. normalmente, quanto menos tiver de reinventar a pólvora, maior será a produtividade a médio longo prazo. e existe sempre a possibilidade de refinar o seu produto a médio longo prazo. como lhe digo, ao início, quanto mais puder simplificar a implementação do seu produto, melhor.

Comment: pense também na possibilidade de incluir código em ruby on rails, node.Js e angular.Js  na sua aplicação. são ferramentas bastante poderosas e rápidas, e poderá concerteza encontrar no github imensos templates, sobre como incorporar isso numa aplicação de android. veJa o reference manual de cada uma dessas APIs/Frameworks, e de uma vista de olhos a alguns tutoriais no youtube. o utilizador de youtube derek banas tem tutoriais, de introdução bastante extensivos, e compreensivos, e acessíveis

Comment: node e angular correm em Javascript, portanto não será problema inclui-las em Java. quanto ao ruby on rails. não tenho a certeza, mas também não deverá ser problemático, de todo